# How to combine multiple objects into a single array in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

below i am creating an object by looping through two lists, but I want the objects i am creating to be added to a single array, how can I achieve this, my first attempt is below,

this is the format of data I'm looking for or trying to achieve

```
var schema = [
  {name: 'Name', type: 'STRING'},
  {name: 'Age', type: 'INTEGER'},
  {name: 'Weight', type: 'FLOAT'},
  {name: 'IsMagic', type: 'BOOLEAN'},
];
```

here is my object and the array i want to add the objects to

```
var data = [];

class dataObject {
  String name;
  String type;

  dataObject({required this.name, required this.type});
}
```

here is my attempt to create the objects by looping through two different lists and add it to an array

```
for (var i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < listB.length; i++) {


        var newObject =
            dataObject(
                name: listA[i],
                type: listB[i]);
        

        data.add(dataObject);

        print(data);
    }
```

this method is giving me errors

Comment: Use another variable name than i in the second loop

Comment: `this method is giving me errors` show the erros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you

```
            List<dynamic> data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) {
              dataObject newObject =
                  new dataObject(name: listA[i], type: listB[i]);
              data.add(newObject);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              print("${data[i].name},${data[i].type}");
            }
             //print(data);
```

Mistakes in your code:

No need to use two for loop, even you can check with if condition
Also while adding an object you are adding a class name, it should be `data.add(newObject);`

Comment: you're a life saver thanks ,been stuck for a while

Comment: do you know how i could encode  the data array in JSON? i used jsonEncode(newObject) but i keep getting the error Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'dataObject',